# error:libtool failed with exit code 1 using Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, wxwidgets, libtool-xcode

I am trying to compile a c++ project into a lib, using Xcode 4.6.
Also it is a wxWidgets project
I chose C/C++ Library when build the project 
then I and my files 
and click build, the error like this

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1

I'v taken hours to fix it but nothing useful, please advise, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Find an error noting  compiling failed, because Reachability is missing. I'd propose that you check your compiling environment has latest (or compatible) version of the library.And give me what happens

Comment: thank you, I have solved the problem.It's actually because of "other linker flags", I removed 4 flags and it can build successfully.But I don't not why..the 4 flags are  -lexpat -lz -lpthread -liconv